# How to increase _cluster/settings/cluster.max_shards_per_node for AWS Elasticsearch Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I uses AWS Elasticsearch service version 7.1 and its built-it Kibana to manage application logs. New indexes are created daily by Logstash. My Logstash gets error about maximum shards limit reach from time to time and I have to delete old indexes for it to become working again.

I found from this document (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html) that I have an option to increase `_cluster/settings/cluster.max_shards_per_node`.

So I have tried that by put following command in Kibana Dev Tools

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "defaults" : {
      "cluster.max_shards_per_node": "2000"
  }
}
```

But I got this error

```
{
  "Message": "Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."
}
```

Someone suggests that this error occurs when I try to update some settings that are not allowed by AWS, but this document (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_7_1) tells me that `cluster.max_shards_per_node` is one in the allowed list.

Please suggest how to update this settings.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-total-shards.html) states that this setting is unbounded/unlimited. This is clearly not the case as we've experienced.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to rename `defaults` to `persistent`

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
      "cluster.max_shards_per_node": "2000"
  }
}
```

Beware though, that the more shards you allow per node, the more resources each node will need and the worse the performance can get.

Comment: sorry for late response, It works but I forgot to accept your answer.